# If cells in specific sheet equal a specific value, then delete the row

Tags: vba, excel

I am checking all cell in a range. If a cell's value is equal to 0 (the value is generated by a formula) then delete the row.

```
Sub CleanJunk()
    For Each c In Worksheets("testsheet").Range("B33:B533").Cells
        If c.Value = "0" Then Rows(c.Row).EntireRow.Delete
    Next
End Sub
```

Right now the module runs without any error. It just doesn't do anything. No rows get deleted or affected in any way.

Comment: Try `If c.Value = 0` instead

Comment: If I do that, It only take a few more second to run the whole thing. Still, rows don't get affected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You haven't qualified the `Rows` call, and you need to loop backwards:

```
Sub CleanJunk()
  Dim n as long
    for n = 533 to 33 step -1
    If Worksheets("testsheet").Cells(n, "B").Value2 = 0 Then Worksheets("testsheet").Rows(n).EntireRow.Delete
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The key here is that the value is generated by a formula.  It probably contains a floating point error.

Comparing a value to a string `"0"` isn't good coding either - apples with apple not oranges!

To get rid of the floating point error use the `ROUND(Num, # of decimals) with # of decimals = 0

Compare the result to 0.

```
Option Explicit 'so you don't confuse your variables
Sub CleanJunk()
Dim c as range
    For Each c In Worksheets("testsheet").Range("B33:B533").Cells
        'compare values rounded to integer with 0
        If Round(c.Value, 0) = 0 Then c.EntireRow.Delete
    Next c 'it pays to be explicit
End Sub
```